# Auth0 is not defined. angular-auth0, angularjs

Tags: angularjs, auth0

Package.json:

```
"angular-auth0": "3.0.0",
```

app.js

```
import auth0 from 'angular-auth0';
```

Error in console.

```
angular-auth0.js?2d7e:152 Uncaught ReferenceError: auth0 is not defined
```

angular-auth0.js:

```
/***/ }),
/* 2 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = auth0;

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

Using webpack.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you install the `auth0` package as well or just this wrapper?  Both are necessary.

Comment: Maybe also use the auth0 tutorial. They have a great tuturial for Angular SPA.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely missing the *auth0-js* package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0-js

Run:

```
npm install auth0-js
```

Other possible solution:
https://github.com/auth0/angular-auth0/issues/28

```
require('angular-auth0/src');
```